# AlamofireObjectMapper not supporting ios8 when updating to swift 3?

Tags: ios8, alamofire, swift3, objectmapper

I tried to update my project to Swift 3, my project has support for ios8 as well.

While trying to update the cocoapods, I am getting issue that AlamofireObjectMapper requires higher deployment target.

On changing to ios9 the pods install without any error, but I still want to support ios8.

Can anyone help on how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT Alamofire 4.1.0**

Support for iOS 8.0 and macOS 10.10 is back!

---

You cannot update to Swift 3 without dropping support for iOS 8, I'm afraid. The reason is that the Swift 3 version of Alamofire is 4.0 and the developers have decided to drop support for iOS 8.0. The reasons can be found here : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1367#issuecomment-235803404

Therefore you can continue supporting iOS 8 by using the latest Swift 2.3 release of Alamofire (3.5.1) and AlamofireObjectMapper or drop support for iOS 8.

Comment: Well, https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire here they state that:
Requirements

    iOS 8.0+ / macOS 10.10+ / tvOS 9.0+ / watchOS 2.0+
    Xcode 8.1+
    Swift 3.0+

Comment: You're right, they've added support for iOS 8 back since Apple seems to be dropping Swift 2.3. Updating my answer.