# AlamofireObjectMapper not working in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, cocoapods, alamofire, swift3

I developed an app in Swift 2 and I was using objectMapper.

Now iOS 10 has come and I updated my code and pod file and now I am using iOS 10 and working in Swift 3.

I updated my pod file AlamofireObjectMapper 4.0 it not supporting iOS 8.

I have googled about it, but not found any solution.

Comment: Are you running app in iOS8 or iOS 10?

Answer (score 0):

Same answer I've given here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39822443/4552438

> You cannot update to Swift 3 without dropping support for iOS 8, I'm afraid. The reason is that the Swift 3 version of Alamofire is 4.0 and the developers have decided to drop support for iOS 8.0. The reasons can be found here : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1367#issuecomment-235803404
>
> Therefore you can continue supporting iOS 8 by using the latest Swift 2.3 release of Alamofire (3.5.1) and AlamofireObjectMapper or drop support for iOS 8.