# Xcode offers to convert frameworks to Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, objectmapper

I have several frameworks in my project like Realm, Charts and Objectmapper, and I update the pods to the latest versions that support Swift 3. However, when I open the project, Xcode offers to convert these frameworks to Swift 3. When it does, it asks me to unlock some files and when it finishes there are still hundreds of errors.

My question:

Why is it asking me to convert frameworks that already use Swift 3? Does that mean I didn't update them right or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AlamofireObjectMapper not supporting ios8 when updating to swift 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703996/alamofireobjectmapper-not-supporting-ios8-when-updating-to-swift-3)

Comment: build your project again and the errors will go